# ASP.NET TreeView Display images

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

I’m trying to display images in a ASP.NET (web) TreeView control. Basically in the DB there is 1, 2 and/or 3 ticked and everything that is checked should cause an appropriate image(s) to appear next to that node on the tree. This all works except for then there is postback
I’ve used this [http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14031/Displaying-Multiple-Images-In-The-ASP-NET-TreeView] and it works ok, except for when a postback occurs.
In addition to the +- symbols I also use the onselectednodechanged method, this causes the postbacks (this is ok as other things are happening on the page at the same time). But the postback looses the fact that it should display the images and they disappear.

I can only assume that the images are not saved in the viewstate as when the tree is rendered it opens to the correct point but ignores the images.

Is there a better way to have images displayed in a tree view? Or a simple way of telling the view state to remember the images

------------------ Extra info ---------------

I've just watched what happens to the nodes / child nodes during the postback. they revert to there default types. 
When I create them they are created a ImageTreeViewNode which is inherited from the TreeNode.
After the post back the nodes are all TreeNode rather then ImageTreeViewNode. Is there a way to stop them reverting and loosing the extra info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up solving this by extending the TreeView class and the new 'ImageTreeView' class for my treeview control.

I changed the createNode method to use the new ImageTreeNode class (the extended TreeNode class)

Not sue if it's a good or bad solution, but it seams to work.